# Github action -> SSH connection trouble

Tags: shell, github, ssh, github-actions, vps

i have an issue with my github action and i can't connect with ssh i did this :

- Create an ssh key with user adam
- Copy the public key into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
- Create a secret in github with the public key
- Create a script.sh into /home/adam/
- chmod 600 .ssh directory

But i got this error :

Run ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
Warning: Identity file /home/adam/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
Warning: Permanently added 'my Ip' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
adam@my Ip: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.

This is my code :

```
        name: Run script on VPS
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  run-script:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run script
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.VPS_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY }}
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
              -o PasswordAuthentication=no \
              -i /home/adam/.ssh/id_rsa \
              adam@myip \
              "bash /home/adam/script.sh"
```

Can someone help me fix this ?

- tried to verify if the path to the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub is correct
- saw both files were there and with the good key inside
- tried reacreate ssh key multiples time
- tried different way to access ssh
- verify conf open ssh accept rsa and add this line  `CASignatureAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`
- restart service ssh

Comment: `/home/adam` doesn't exist. The root directory after a checkout is stored in the `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` environment variable. Where in your repo is the `.ssh` directory? And, you probably don't want to commit your private key as a file, do you?

Comment: A great way for interactive debugging that lets you SSH into a runner is [tmate](https://github.com/mxschmitt/action-tmate).

Comment: the .ssh is in my vps inside /home/adam

Comment: no i dont want to commit the key what am i missing here ?

Comment: You run the command on a GitHub Actions runner, trying to connect to `adam@myip`. The runner doesn't have access to your VPS, how could that SSH command succeed if the private key is on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your answers I don't know exactly what was the issue but i think it was related with the ssh key

I fixed my code by using password that is store in secret of github instead of ssh key

```
  name: Deploy 
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - master
    jobs:
      deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Install Node.js
            uses: actions/setup-node@v2
            with:
              node-version: '16.x'
          - name: Install dependencies
            run: npm install
          - name: Build project
            run: npm run build
          - name: SSH Deploy
            run: |
              sshpass -p ${{ secrets.PSWD }} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 ${{ secrets.USER}}@${{ secrets.VPS_IP }} 'cd /home/adam && ./deploy.sh'
            env:
              SSHPASS: ${{ secrets.PSWD }}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Copy the public key into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

That is on the remote target server you want to SSH *to*.

And it means you want to SSH to as root: `root@remoteServer:...`.
Not as `adam@...`

---

Instead of relying on local path which does not exist on GitHub runner (unless maybe self-hosted), you might want to use the GitHub Action "[`appleboy/ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action)"

```yaml
  - name: ssh key passphrase
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.9
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
      passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
      script: |
        whoami
        ls -al
```

Remove the `passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}` line if your SSH private key is not passphrase protected.

That way, you do not need to create `.ssh/` folder with the right permission. That action takes care of all that for you.